# Change the marker position in Google Maps 3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am creating a Google Map with a draggable marker. After I created the marker, how can I change its position later on? Can I use `setposition(latlng)` for this? If yes, how?
Here is my code where I am creating a Google Map 3 instance:

```
function showm(la,lo) {
  $('#gmap').hide();
  alert(lo);
  $('#gmap').gmap3({
    marker:{
      latLng: [la,lo],
      options:{
        draggable:true
      },
      events:{
        dragend: function(marker){
          $(this).gmap3({
            getaddress:{
              latLng:marker.getPosition(),
              callback:function(results){
                alert(marker.getPosition().lat());
                var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                  infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:"infowindow"}),
                  content = results && results[1] ? results[0].formatted_address : "no address";
                if (infowindow){
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  infowindow.setContent(content);
                } else {
                  $(this).gmap3({
                    infowindow:{
                      anchor:marker,
                      options:{content: content}
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
    map:{
      options:{
        zoom: 12
      }
    }
  });
  $('#gmap').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any progress? :) Can't help you with precisely what you're asking, but if you haven't 
already gone too far in using that plugin, I'd venture to suggest another solution 
in terms of another jQuery plugin ([landcarte](http://attimes.org/landcarte/)).

The code from your post would look like the following:
(Guess it looks more readable and jQuery-like)

```
var map = $("#map").geoMap();
var balloon = map.balloon();

var showMap = function(lat, lon) {
    map.attr({ center: [lat, lon], zoom: 12 })
       .add("marker", { position: [lat, lon], draggable: true });
    var marker = map.find("markers").eq(0);
    marker.on("dragend", function(event) {
        map.search(event.location, function(data) {
            balloon.show({ position: marker.attr("position"), content: data.address || "?" });
        });
    });
};

showMap(55.68, 12.56);
```

As to your question: once the map is initialized, the marker's position can be 
changed this way

```
map.find("markers").eq(0).attr({ position: [55.68, 12.56] });
```